# Docker container app cannot log to host /var/log

Tags: docker

The initial version of our Docker app had the app running as root in the container. The app mounted the /var/log/app directory in the container to the same directory structure on the host. Everything was fine and logging was good.

In an effort to make the app more secure, we create a user in the Dockerfile and run the app as that user and map the /home/apprunner/log directory to the /var/log/app directory on the host.

Logging no longer appears in the /var/log/app directory on the host, although we can still stream it via stout. We suspect that it is a permission issue.

Is there a canonical way to run a non-root app in the container and map it to a /var/log directory on the container?

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a /var/log/user folder and `chown` that to the user you're running the container as?

Comment: We did try this - but the problem is that the user on the host is not the same as the user in the container. So giving the /var/log/whatever directory on the host to a user won't work because that user (in the container) is not the same user as the one on the host.